# Does my Lenovo IdeaCentre 720-18asu PC (with an AMD Radeon R5 340 video card) support 4k video?

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer, amd-radeon, 4k-resolution, lenovo-desktop-computer

As the title says, I was wondering if my computer will support 4K video.

I do not know much about this computer other than it’s a Lenovo IdeaCentre 720-18asu. I have not been able to find anything through research, but from what I see the computer has an AMD Radeon R5 340 graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

If it indeed has an AMD Radeon R5 340, it should support 4K if you have a 4K quality display port cable.

I didn’t see anything useful [on AMD’s site](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r5-series/amd-radeon-r5-300-series/amd-radeon-r5-340) but [this Amazon listing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072HGFKF6) does mention 4K support.

I couldn't find if there was a difference between the 340 and 340x. The 2GB of memory you mentioned prior to your question being edited referred to what was available specifically on your graphics card - I could not find that model of computer being sold with anything less than 8GB of memory, so you should be fine on that front.

If you’re aiming for 4K just make sure you have a 4K monitor with a resolution supported by your graphics card, and a 4K cable connecting them.